# Cosa significa "rullo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Se una notte d'inverno un viaggiatore* d'Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Avevo un bel dire ogni volta: che sollievo, rimetto il 
>   contachilometri a zero, passo la spugna sulla lavagna: l'indomani 
>   del giorno in cui ero arrivato in un paese nuovo già questo zero era diventato un numero di tante cifre che non stava più sui *rulli*, 
>   che occupava la lavagna da un capo all'altro, persone, posti, 
>   simpatie, antipatie, passi falsi.

Non riesco a capire il significato di "rulli" in questa frase. Ho cercato il vocabolo "rullo" in alcuni dizionari, ma nessuna delle accezioni sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "rulli" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Penso che si riferisca ai rulli nel senso di piccoli cilindri rotanti con impresse le cifre da 0 a 9, che formano il numero dei chilometri percorsi in un contachilometri, così:
[image: contachilometri]